# Ionic React: How to make a long press gesture for an image in Ionic React?

Tags: reactjs, ionic4, long-press

I am new to **Ionic React** and I am looking to make a long press event for an image. It seems that they removed the function from react from this version because of some errors. Is there a way to make it manually?

Thanks